# Converting a set of characters into a different string array using java

Tags: java, android, arrays, file

I am trying to read a data from a file. I have following code.

```
  public void ReadFile()
  {
      File sdcard = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();  
      File directory = new File(sdcard.getAbsolutePath()+ "/MyDirectory");  
      File file = new File(directory,"textfile1.txt");  
      try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) {
          char stringComma = new Character(',');
          System.out.println("Total file size to read (in bytes) : "+ fis.available());
          int content;
          while ((content = fis.read()) != -1) {
              // convert to char and display it
              Log.d(TAG, "reading a file");
              System.out.print((char) content);
          }
      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
```

I have file format as follows [textfile1.txt]

```
  [12],84359768069 //some numbers
  [34],56845745740
  [44],36344679992
  [99],46378467467
```

When i am reading this file each character will read at a time. I want to split this and store in different string arrays like

```
  str1 = [12]
  str2 = 84359768069
```

How i can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're currently reading a *byte* at a time, because you're using `InputStream`. That's the first thing to fix - you should be using a `Reader` for text data. The best approach is to wrap your `InputStream` in an `InputStreamReader`.

Next, it sounds like you want to read a *line* at a time rather than just a character at a time. The easiest way of doing that is to use a `BufferedReader` wrapping an `InputStreamReader`.

(If you were using Java 7+, all of this could be achieved very nicely using [`Files.newBufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-) - you just need to supply the `Path` and the `Charset`. Until Android supports that, you'll need to just do the wrapping manually. It's not too painful though.)

One you're reading a line at a time, you then need to split the line by comma - look at using `String.split` for this. I would then suggest you create a class to store these two separate values. So each line will be transformed into an instance of your class.

Finally, create a `List<YourCustomClass>` and add to it as you read the file.

That's given an overview of how to achieve each step - hopefully enough detail to enable you to get going, but not spoon-feeding you enough to hamper you actually learning from the experience.

Answer (score -1):

A simple solution would be to parse the readed characters:

```
public void ReadFile()
{
  File sdcard = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();  
  File directory = new File(sdcard.getAbsolutePath()+ "/MyDirectory");  
  File file = new File(directory,"textfile1.txt");  
  try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) {
      char stringComma = new Character(',');
      System.out.println("Total file size to read (in bytes) : "+ fis.available());
      int content;
      String str1="";
      String str2 = "";
      boolean commaFound=false;
      while ((content = fis.read()) != -1) {
          // convert to char and display it
          Log.d(TAG, "reading a file");
          if ((char)content==',')
          {
             commaFound = true;
          }
          else if ((char)content=="\n")
          {
              System.out.printlnt("str1="+str1+"\nstr2="+str2);
              commaFound = false;
              str1 = "";
              str2 = "";
          }
          else
          {
             if (commaFound)
             {
               str2 += (char)content;
             }
             else
             {
               str1 += (char)content;
             }
          }
          System.out.print((char) content);
      }
  } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: That looks considerably *less* simple than using a `BufferedReader` to read a line at a time, and `String.split` to split the string on commas... it's also repeating the mistake of using an `InputStream` directly to read text. Oh, and it's using string concatenation in a loop, which is unpleasant.

Comment: @JonSkeet I totally agree with you. I said it was simple because it is easy to understanda character by character read... But I agree that a `BufferedReader` solution would be much better.